# section of a complex line bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

In quantum mechanics the wave function is complex valued function.How ever in  some approach it is seen as section of a complex line bundle. what is the difference between a section of a complex line bundle and a complex valued function?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a complex valued function and a section of a line bundle is similar to the difference between a scalar field and a component of a vector field.

The value of a component of a vector field no only depends on the point where the field is evaluated, but also on the *basis* chosen.

**Edit**
Following on from the comment below.

A section of a line bundle is like a vector field. It is a map $s:M \rightarrow L$ such that $s(m) \in L_m$ or $\pi \circ s(m)=m$. So a Section of a line bundle is one-to-one.

Example. For the trivial bundle $L=M \times \mathbb{C}$,  every section $s$ looks like $s(x)=(x,f(x))$ for some function $f$.

Comment: what does a section depend on?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira Please see update to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're missing the point with this answer. A complex-valued function is indeed a section of the *trivial* complex line bundle over $M$ (where you can choose a globally-defined basis), whereas a section of a nontrivial line bundle may be twisted (representing the fact that you cannot choose a globally-defined basis). Think of a Möbius strip as a line bundle over the circle, as compared with a cylinder.